# draw Markov chain with tikz, with states only portionally colored

Tags: tikz-styles

i would like to draw a Markov chain, to show the difference between transient state and steady state with time abstract evolution of a CTMC, like in the images: [image: CTMC changes with time epoch]

I search for portionally filling color, but couldn't get a clue, any help would be very thankful.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. I suggest to start from http://steventhornton.ca/blog/markov-chains-in-latex.html

Comment: Pleas show us, what you try so far (that we not need to design chain from scratch). For coloring of node you need to define new nodes style. For half red circle can be handy `shapes.multipart` library, more hard is define quarter red circle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Defining the partial height is interesting: if *A* is the area of a circle, you have to solve *x = t - sin(t) / 2pi* to find the central angle *t* formed by the segment with area *x * A*.  I can't do that in TikZ but here is an effort in [Metapost](http://www.tug.org/metapost.html).  I have drawn your third diagram:

[image]

Here is the source. Compile with `lualatex`.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luatex85}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1);
    numeric node_diameter;
    node_diameter = 21;

    interim ahangle := 30;
    interim ahlength := 6;

    vardef connection(expr a, b, bend) = 
        a {(b-a) rotated bend} .. b
            cutbefore fullcircle scaled node_diameter shifted a
            cutafter fullcircle scaled (node_diameter+2) shifted b
    enddef;

    vardef loop(expr a, m) = 
        fullcircle scaled abs (m - a) shifted 5/8[a, m]
            cutbefore halfcircle scaled node_diameter shifted a
            cutafter  halfcircle scaled node_diameter rotated 180 shifted a
    enddef;

    vardef find(expr p) =
        lo_ := 0; hi_ := 360;
        forever:
            x_ := 1/2[lo_, hi_];
            exitif abs (hi_ - lo_) <= tolerance;
            if (0.017453292519943295 x_ - sind(x_)) < 6.283185307179586 p: lo_ else: hi_ fi := x_;
        endfor
        x_ / 90
    enddef;

    vardef partial_node(expr p) = 
        if p <= 0:
            fullcircle scaled eps
        elseif p < 1:
            numeric x; x = find(p);
            subpath (6-x, 6+x) of fullcircle scaled node_diameter -- cycle
        else:
            fullcircle scaled node_diameter
        fi
    enddef;

    x1 = x4 = 0; x2 = x5 = 120; x3 = x6 = 240;
    y1 = y2 = y3 = 0; y4 = y5 = y6 = -100;

    path c[]; 
    c12 = connection(z1, z2, 30);
    c21 = connection(z2, z1, 30);
    c23 = connection(z2, z3, 0);

    c14 = connection(z1, z4, 0);
    c44 = loop(z4, z4 shifted 28 left);
    c25 = connection(z2, z5, 0);
    c36 = connection(z3, z6, 36);
    c63 = connection(z6, z3, 36);

    forsuffixes $ = 12, 21, 23, 14, 44, 25, 36, 63:
        drawarrow c$;
    endfor

    label.top("$21$", point 1/2 of c12);
    label.lft("$21$", point 1/2 of c14);

    label.bot("$8$", point 1/2 of c21);
    label.top("$4$", point 1/2 of c23);
    label.rt ("$4$", point 1/2 of c25);

    label.lft("$10$", point 4 of c44);

    drawoptions(withcolor 1/2[red, white]);

    fill partial_node(1/3) shifted z1;

    fill partial_node(1/4) shifted z3;
    fill partial_node(1/2) shifted z4;
    fill partial_node(1/4) shifted z5;

    drawoptions();

    forsuffixes $ = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6:
        draw fullcircle scaled node_diameter shifted z$;
    endfor

endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

### Notes

- The parameter `node_diameter` controls the size of the nodes to draw / fill
- `ahangle` and `ahlength` control the shape of the arrow heads in plain MP
- the `connection` macro returns an optionally curved connecting path from `a` to `b`
- the `loop` macro returns a loop at `a` that passes through `m`
- the `find` macro is adapted from the standard `solve` macro to solve the equation given above.  The answer is divided by 90 to get the appropriate "points" around a circle
- the `partial_node` macro returns a cyclic path representing the amount to be filled

I've tried to keep everything as simple and "plain" as possible.

Answer (score 2):

Translate Thruston's answer to Asymptote.

```
import plain_boxesExtra; // https://github.com/justonly011298/plain_boxesExtra

unitsize(1cm);
size(300);
real margin=3mm;
defaultpen(fontsize(10pt));
pair A[]={(0,0),(0,-1),(1,0),(1,-1),(2,0),(2,-1)};
object O[];
for (int i=0; i<A.length; ++i){ O.push(draw("",pscircle,A[i],margin,invisible)); }
add(new void(frame f, transform t) {
pen Pen=red+opacity(.5);
fill(f,arc(point(O[0],(S+N)/2,t),point(O[0],dir(-160),t),point(O[0],dir(-20),t))--cycle,Pen);
fill(f,arc(point(O[1],(S+N)/2,t),point(O[1],dir(-180),t),point(O[1],dir(0),t))--cycle,Pen);
fill(f,arc(point(O[3],(S+N)/2,t),point(O[3],dir(-150),t),point(O[3],dir(-30),t))--cycle,Pen);
fill(f,arc(point(O[4],(S+N)/2,t),point(O[4],dir(-150),t),point(O[4],dir(-30),t))--cycle,Pen);
for (int i=0; i<A.length; ++i) 
draw(f,circle(point(O[i],(S+N)/2,t),abs(point(O[i],(S+N)/2,t)-point(O[i],S,t))));
picture pic;
draw(pic,"$20$",point(O[0],S,t)--point(O[1],N,t),Arrow);
draw(pic,"$10$",arc(point(O[1],W,t)-2mm,point(O[1],dir(135),t),point(O[1],dir(-135),t)),Arrow);
draw(pic,"$21$",point(O[0],dir(30),t){dir(30)}..{dir(-30)}point(O[2],dir(150),t),LeftSide,Arrow);
draw(pic,"$8$",point(O[2],dir(-150),t){dir(-150)}..{dir(150)}point(O[0],dir(-30),t),LeftSide,Arrow);
draw(pic,"$4$",point(O[2],E,t)--point(O[4],W,t),LeftSide,Arrow);
draw(pic,"$4$",point(O[2],S,t)--point(O[3],N,t),LeftSide,Arrow);
draw(pic,point(O[4],dir(-45),t){dir(-60)}..{dir(-120)}point(O[5],dir(45),t),Arrow);
draw(pic,point(O[5],dir(135),t){dir(120)}..{dir(60)}point(O[4],dir(-135),t),Arrow);
add(f,pic.fit());
});
```

[image]